# AVC adbclient action failed with RuntimeError

Tags: python, androidviewclient

I have a simple code snippet as below using AVC to perform some sequential actions to a Nexus3 phone.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import sys, os, time

try:
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME'], 'src'))
except:
    pass

from com.dtmilano.android.adb.adbclient import AdbClient
#from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient

adbc=AdbClient(serialno='.*')
print 'taking snapshot...'
adbc.takeSnapshot()
print 'touch 1st time...'
adbc.touch(50,70)
time.sleep(1)
print 'touch 2nd time...'
adbc.touch(50,70)
```

with the takeSnapshot() code before touch(), the touch() failed with below exception:

```
touch 1st time...
sending 0015shell:input tap 50 70
shell(cmd=input tap 50 70)
__send(shell:input tap 50 70, checkok=True, reconnect=False)
__checkOk()
checkConnected()
    checkConnected: returning True
setAlarm(150)
    __checkOk: recv= ''
setAlarm(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/swang/engine/test.py", line 19, in <module>
    adbc.touch(50,70)
  File "/home/swang/engine/com/dtmilano/android/adb/adbclient.py", line 430, in touch
    self.shell('input tap %d %d' % (x, y))
  File "/home/swang/engine/com/dtmilano/android/adb/adbclient.py", line 260, in shell
    self.__send('shell:%s' % cmd, checkok=True, reconnect=False)
  File "/home/swang/engine/com/dtmilano/android/adb/adbclient.py", line 157, in __send
    self.__checkOk()
  File "/home/swang/engine/com/dtmilano/android/adb/adbclient.py", line 193, in __checkOk
    raise RuntimeError("ERROR: %s %s" % (repr(recv), error))
RuntimeError: ERROR: '' 
Closing socket... <socket._socketobject object at 0xa9da60>
```

but if I remove the takeSnapshot(), the following 2 touch() would be successful. I'm using the recent AVC release. Am I overlooking something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For historical reasons `AdbClient.takeSnapshot()` is defined as

```
def takeSnapshot(self, reconnect=False):
   ...
```

which means that there will be a disconnection after taking the screenshot.
So all you have to do in your script is

```
...
adbc=AdbClient(serialno='.*')
print 'taking snapshot...'
adbc.takeSnapshot(reconnect=True)
print 'touch 1st time...'
adbc.touch(50,70)
time.sleep(1)
print 'touch 2nd time...'
adbc.touch(50,70)
```

and it will work.